# In a Thymeleaf `th:text` tag, how do I show different text on `if int == -1`?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this in a `Thymeleaf` web page ...

```html
<span th:text="${account.balance}">balance</span>
```

When the `account.balance == -1` that means unknown, so I want to display text `"Unknown"`.

How do I do an `if account.balance == -1 show 'Unknown'` in `Thymleaf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole lot of ways to do this... I would just suggest reading through the Thymeleaf [conditional evaluation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation) documentation.

I'd probably do something like this, myself:

```
<th:block th:switch="${account.balance}">
    <span th:case="-1">Unknown</span>
    <span th:case="*" th:text="${account.balance}" />
</th:block>
```

You could also do some thing like this:

```
<span th:if="${account.balance == -1}">Unknown</span>
<span th:unless="${account.balance == -1}" th:text="${account.balance}" />
```

Or you could build a String:

```
<span th:text="${account.balance == -1 ? 'Unknown' : account.balance}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `<span th:if="${account.balance == -1}">Unknown</span>`

But this : [page](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals) will be very much helpful for conditionals in general